# Error on Newsletter Subscribers

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, debugging

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in
>
> /home/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Resource/Subscriber/Collection.php
> on line 139

**I get this error when I click on Newsletter Subscribers.**

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Did you modify any customer related settings or customer attributes? Is this a new & clean install of Magento? If not, did it work before?

Comment: We are a couple years split from a clean install. This is a 5 server cluster at this point. Attributes do pin a good starting point as we started build a custom permission system. Is this any documentation on the customer attributes? I could look at a clean install and start from there too.

Comment: Check out the DB this morning, All attributes seem to be intact.

Comment: So did you run any extension updates/installs/de-installs? Mysterious!

Comment: Does the page in the backend load now?